# significant eye sight drop from using Macbook Pro retina

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I've been using the Macbook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, late 2013 model) for 1.5 years now, and I've noticed my eye sight has **dropped significantly since then**. The time I spent on computer was the same as before (about 14 hours/day, I'm a programmer). Before this, I was using a desktop with mid-tier screen, and had no problem. Now my eyes get easily tired and strained after 30 minutes of looking at the Macbook screen.

If you have experienced similar problems, I would really appreciate if you can share any advice about it, and possibly solutions? My work is on programming, it hard for me to switch to another career :s

Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen an ophthalmologist?

Comment: The problem with supper high resolution screens is they provide to many details, so you strain your eyes in trying to see every detail (unconsciously). That is why with the mid-tier screen you had no problems. With 14h/day your eyes will get tired, so try switching to lower resolution (bigger screen).

Comment: @Buscar웃SD thanks a lot for your response, is it also a personal issue you had with?

Comment: @Buscar웃SD, Do you have an authoritative source you can link regarding your comment or is it just conjecture?

Comment: How old are you? Presbyopia is a factor to consider if the answer is 40-50. Also, 14h work day?

Answer (score 1):

For me it's glassy screen coat and huge brightness. Just lower the brightness and make smaller resolution also use night shift